# vm exception while processing transaction invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, remix

I have been running this code in remix but getting error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

// import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {

    uint public dieselPriceUSD;
    string public re;

    event LogNewDieselPrice(string price);
    event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);

    constructor() public {
        update(); // First check at contract creation...
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string memory result) public {
        // require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress(),"cda");
        emit LogNewDieselPrice(result);
        re = result;
        // Log(result);
        // dieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // Let's save it as cents...
        // Now do something with the USD Diesel price...
    }

    function update() public payable {
        emit LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer...");
        oraclize_query("URL", "xml(http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss).rss.channel.item.0.title","asd");
    }
}
```

In truffle the error was invalid opcode,

in remix it shows  error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.

Please help

Comment: what did you try in remix. What was the error you got?

Comment: invalid opcode ,

Comment: what did you try to get that error?

Comment: @SanjaySB i didn't get you, I just ran this code in remix.ethereum.org

Comment: In Remix, first the code should be compilable before you can deploy it in the run tab.

Comment: I can see about four error is the compile tab when I copied the code. Please refactor the code and try again.

Comment: it compiles properly, there are 4 warning, just about unused variable , make sure to use compiler version 0.5.8

Comment: https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94204/discussion-between-sanjay-s-b-and-lokesh-kumar).